# Textures are only appearing on Texture Paint tab

Tags: texturing

I imported a .DAE file with JPEG textures.
Blender is not showing these textures in any tab...
[image]

... except Texture Paint tab:
[image]

How to see the textures in all tabs?

Comment: Why this is necessary for layout? ...Anyway, you would have to set the viewport shading (at least) to 'Textured'. You can either press *Z* or use the buttons with the sphere icons on the top right of the 3d View: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/display/shading.html

Comment: @brockmann Tks, but I can't see such option: Pressing Z I only see Material Preview, WireFrame, Solid and Rendered.

Comment: Also, I fixed the title, actually, the textures are not appearing in any tab, except Texture Paint

Answer (score 1):

Inside the viewport press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and select texture paint or press <kbd>9</kbd> and you will see the same view as in texture paint Work space.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the dropdown on the top right, in the *Color* section, select the *Texture* option. If the *Material* one is selected, I have the same problem you mentioned

In the *Lighting* section you should have the *Studio* one selected by default.

[image: top right]